# Get Maven to download complete opendaylight sources

Tags: eclipse, maven, debugging, m2eclipse, opendaylight

I am trying to debug my opendaylight module by attaching the eclipse debugger. Unfortunately eclipse is not able to locate the source files of several dependencies managed by maven.

I already tried the "Download Sources" action from eclipses m2 plugin, as well did i run

```
mvn eclipse:eclipse -DdownloadSources=true
```

The above resulted in a download of some sources. Strangely there is still something missing. In my specific case i would need the source of the ***sal.implementation*** artifact in order to analyze the ***FlowProgrammerService*** class

In my project's .pom-files sal.implementation is not listed as a dependency but under "Import-Package"

```
<build>
<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.6</version>
    <extensions>true</extensions>
    <configuration>
      <instructions>
        <Import-Package>
          org.opendaylight.controller.sal.core,
          org.opendaylight.controller.sal.utils,
          org.opendaylight.controller.sal.packet,
          org.opendaylight.controller.sal.match,
          org.opendaylight.controller.sal.action,
          org.opendaylight.controller.sal.flowprogrammer,
          org.opendaylight.controller.switchmanager,
          org.apache.felix.dm,
          org.osgi.service.component,
          org.slf4j,
          org.eclipse.osgi.framework.console,
          org.osgi.framework
        </Import-Package>
        <Export-Package>
          org.opendaylight.controller.tutorial_L2_forwarding
        </Export-Package>
        <Bundle-Activator>
          org.opendaylight.controller.tutorial_L2_forwarding.internal.Activator
        </Bundle-Activator>
      </instructions>
      <manifestLocation>${project.basedir}/META-INF</manifestLocation>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
</plugins>
```

Only the distribution/opendaylight/pom.xml lists sal.implementation as a dependency.

```
...
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.opendaylight.controller</groupId>
  <artifactId>sal.implementation</artifactId>
</dependency>
...
```

Now, how do i tell maven to download these additional sources? Is there a different way to attach those sources in a way eclipse can handle it?

Answer (score 0):

You can install the JBoss Tools Maven integration feature, which basically enhances m2e's automatic source lookup mechanism. See http://tools.jboss.org/features/maven.html#enhanced-source-lookup-mechanism